# PHP usort tree array

Tags: php, sorting, recursion

I want to sort a tree hierarchy array with structure as below based on a key (in this example: *timestamp*).

```
$topics = array(
  array('name' => 'n1', 'timestamp' => 5000, 'children' => array()),
  array('name' => 'n2', 'timestamp' => 4000, 'children' => array(
    array('name' => 'n3', 'timestamp' => 6000, 'children' => array()),
    array('name' => 'n4', 'timestamp' => 2000, 'children' => array(
      array('name' => 'n5', 'timestamp' => 4000, 'children' => array()),
      array('name' => 'n6', 'timestamp' => 3000, 'children' => array())
    )), 
  )),
  array('name' => 'n7', 'timestamp' => 1000, 'children' => array())
);
```

My sort function:

```
function sequenceSort(&$a, &$b) {
  if (!empty($a['children'])) {
    usort($a['children'], 'sequenceSort');
  }
  if ($a['timestamp'] == $b['timestamp']) {
    return 0;
  }
  return $a['timestamp'] < $b['timestamp'] ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($topics, 'sequenceSort');
print_a($topics);
```

At some levels it produces the correct output, at another it doesn't, e.g:

```
1000 ✔
4000 ✔
   6000 ✘
   2000 ✘
      4000 ✘
      3000 ✘
5000 ✔
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: You cant modify an array inside `usort`

Comment: @kaspars I use pass by references to achieve that.

Comment: Note that you should order your input array differently to see if it really sorts. The second level now also fails but you don't see that because you have already sorted it correctly.

Comment: @jeroen I've edited the question with more random input order.

Comment: @emix It should be <=> (single =), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because `usort()` doesn't pass the array elements by reference, even though you've declared the parameters with `&`. I added:

```
$a['touched'] = true;
```

to the comparison function, and when I printed the result these keys were nowhere to be found.

However, even if it worked, this seems like a very poor way to do it, as it will sort the children multiple times -- every time the parent is being compared with another parent, it will have to re-sort the children, and grandchildren, etc.

It would be better to write a recursive function that sorts one level, then iterates over the children, and so on.

```
function sortRecurse(&$array) {
    usort($array, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['timestamp'] - $b['timestamp'];
    });
    foreach ($array as &$subarray) {
        sortRecurse($subarray['children']);
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/KLbQP8)

Comment: That's what I thought, but this does not sort correctly either.

Comment: @JustinusHermawan It doesn't work because the elements aren't passed by reference to the comparison function. So Kaspar's comment above is correct.

Comment: @barmar Yes, it works. So, the mistake here is `usort()` function does not retrieve params by reference, right?

Comment: It gets its own parameter by reference, but it doesn't pass parameters to the comparison function by reference.

Comment: so bad, i am late http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b438078b739b81c69a5eaa10040415a2c984155c

Comment: Don't assign to `$topics[$i][]`. `recSort()` modifies the array in place, it doesn't return anything.